# AVAudio - iOS Swift development

Tags: ios, swift

So I am using macincloud.com and I have noticed that audio does not work on there service.

I am trying to work out if the code I have is working or not.

and the logs show the following

```
2019-11-21 20:52:06.631378+1100 DRN1[32471:480729] Warning: Attempt to present <AVPlayerViewController: 0x7fc559023800> on <DRN1.ViewController: 0x7fc55750a060> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2019-11-21 20:52:07.068140+1100 DRN1[32471:480856] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-11-21 20:52:07.489403+1100 DRN1[32471:480856] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-11-21 20:52:07.490720+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.490906+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.491021+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.491540+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.491876+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.492183+1100 DRN1[32471:480853]  AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
2019-11-21 20:52:07.493201+1100 DRN1[32471:480856] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
```

My Code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  DRN1
//
//  Created by user160301 on 11/21/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 RadioMedia. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream.m3u") else {
        return
        }
    // Create a new AVPlayer and associate it with the player view
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

           // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
           let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
           controller.player = player

           // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
           present(controller, animated: true) {
               player.play()
           }

    }

    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006") else {
            return
        }
        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }


}
```